# Magento 2: Get list of products on basis of attribute code

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.2

Is there any way I can fetch list of products having a `attribute_code`.

**For eg:
Getting list of all products which has attribute color**

Answer (score 1):

You can use addFieldToFilter for collection filter by using a custom attribute.

Try this:

```
protected $productCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory  $productCollectionFactory

){
     $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
}

$productcollection = $this->productCollectionFactory
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code',array('eq' => value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to filter your product collection if the product has **color** attribute.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productCollection = $objectManager->get("Magento\Catalog\Model\Product")->getCollection();

$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect("color")->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
        array('attribute'=> 'color','notnull' => true),
        array('attribute'=> 'color','neq' => ''),
        array('attribute'=> 'color','neq' => 'NO FIELD'),
    ),'','left'
);

$productIds = array();

foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
    $productIds[] = $product->getId();
}

print_r($productIds);
```

If you want to filter specific option of any attribute. **(red option of color attribute)**, then you can simply filter your products as below.

```
$attributes = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface');
$color = $attributes->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'color');
$optionId = $color->getSource()->getOptionId('red');

$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect("color")->addAttributeToFilter('color',$optionId); 

    $productIds = array();

    foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
        $productIds[] = $product->getId();
    }

    print_r($productIds);
```

> Note : It's a good practice to use `objectManager` by dependency
>   injection.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your code?

Comment: Above code will filter those products which have not null or blank value in color attribute.

Comment: I am not getting list of product ids here.

Comment: post your code in question.

Comment: I need help with code to get product ids on from attribute code.

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67176/discussion-between-deep-joshi-and-dinesh-yadav).